# Baseboard heater - how to fill a hole?

Tags: repair, pipe, heater, baseboard

I found a hole inside my baseboard heater, by the dial on the right hand side, right where the copper pipe meets the wall. Can I use regular Great Stuff to fill the gap, even if it’s touching the pipe? Does the pipe get hot? How can I fill the gap? I need to as mice get into my apartment through it!

Comment: Mice like eating/chewing stuff like Great Stuff.  You really need need to get rid of the mice first.  Then metal screening/steel wool might block that hole from mice, but does not stop them from making another hole.

Comment: Copper mesh or even old fashion steel wool would be better than spray foam.

Answer (score 1):

There's a spray foam specifically made to block mice. Every brand of insulation spray foam sells one, just search online for it. The one from Great Stuff is called Pestblock.

You might want to stuff the hole with steel wool before the foam. It works great.

To solve the mice issue, $1 mouse traps are still the best. Mice around my house like peanut butter.

Comment: Another question that had this product, if searching on the product FAQs even mentions using screening/steel wool inside of the spray stuff, spray some, use steel wool/screening, spray some more.

Comment: Last time we had a mouse problem, after all the various gadgets and poisoned bait and so on didn't work, the pest control company placed a couple of [ordinary traps](https://amzn.to/45BOH6j) and the problem was resolved pretty quickly.